# How to share ajax results between two components with the first one using the second?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

First of all, I'm a beginner with VueJS, so I may presenting you a bunch of non-sens. :-) I read all the beginner doc, but I'm still stuck for this case.

I have 2 template component managed by a functionnal component:

```
<template>
  <h2>PageSpeed performance score: {{ results.score }}.</h2>
</template>
```

The second one, using the first one (the first one is needed to be used elsewhere to display score only:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <template v-if="results">
      <hosting-performance-score :results="results"/>

      <div
        v-for="(result, rule) in results.rules"
        v-if="result.ruleImpact > 0"
        :key="rule"
        class="panel panel-default"
      >
        <div class="panel-heading">{{ result.localizedRuleName }}</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <p>
            {{ result.summary.format }}

            <b>{{ result.ruleImpact }}</b>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </template>
    <i
      v-else
      class="fa fa-spin fa-spinner"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import HostingPerformanceScore from './HostingPerformanceScore';

  export default {
    components: {
      HostingPerformanceScore,
    },
  };
</script>
```

And then, the functional one with the AJAX logic:

```
<script>
  import axios from 'axios';
  import axiosRetry from 'axios-retry';
  import HostingPerformanceScore from './HostingPerformanceScore';
  import HostingPerformancePage from './HostingPerformancePage';

  axiosRetry(axios);

  export default {
    functional: true,
    props: {
      scoreOnly: {
        default: false,
        type: Boolean,
      },
      slug: {
        required: true,
        type: String,
      },
    },
    data: () => ({
      results: null,
    }),
    created() {
      axios.get(Routing.generate('hosting_performance_pagespeed', {
        slug: this.slug,
      })).then((response) => {
        this.results = {
          rules: Object.entries(response.data.formattedResults.ruleResults).map((entry) => {
            const result = entry[1];

            result.ruleName = entry[0];

            return result;
          }).sort((result1, result2) => result1.ruleImpact < result2.ruleImpact),
          score: response.data.ruleGroups.SPEED.score,
        };
      });
    },
    render: (createElement, context) => {
      return createElement(
        context.props.scoreOnly ? HostingPerformanceScore : HostingPerformancePage,
        context.data,
        context.children
      );
    },
  };
</script>
```

The issue is: I can't access the result and I don't know how to pass it properly: `Property or method "results" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.`

Or maybe functional components are not designed for this, but I don't know how to achieve it otherway. How would you do it?

Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have this a little backwards in terms of which components can be functional and which not.

Since your `HostingPerformanceScore` and `HostingPerformancePage` components are really only rendering data, *they* can be functional components by just rendering props they accept.

Your other component has to maintain state, and so it cannot be a functional component.

I put together an example of how this might work.

**HostingPerformanceScore**

```
<template functional>
  <h2 v-if="props.results">
    PageSpeed performance score: {{ props.results.score }}.
  </h2>
</template>
```

**HostingPerformancePage**

```
<template functional>
  <div>
    <h2>Hosting Performance Page</h2>
    <HostingPerformanceScore :results="props.results"/>
  </div>  
</template>

<script>
import HostingPerformanceScore from "./HostingPerformanceScore.vue";
export default {
  components: {
    HostingPerformanceScore
  }
};
</script>
```

**PerformanceResults.vue**

```
<template>
  <HostingPerformanceScore :results="results" v-if="scoreOnly" />
  <HostingPerformancePage :results="results" v-else />
</template>

<script>
import HostingPerformancePage from "./HostingPerformancePage.vue";
import HostingPerformanceScore from "./HostingPerformanceScore.vue";

export default {
  props: {
    scoreOnly: Boolean
  },
  data() {
    return {
      results: null
    };
  },
  created() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.results = {
        score: Math.random()
      };
    }, 1000);
  },
  components: {
    HostingPerformancePage,
    HostingPerformanceScore
  }
};
</script>
```

And here is a [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/3kv8z72y4q).

Comment: Looks great indeed, I'll try, thanks! But it looks the opposite of the documentation sample : https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#Functional-Components WDYT?

Comment: @Soullivaneuh Do you mean that the example you linked uses a render function? I used functional templates for convenience; the Hosting components could just as easily be render functions. The *functional* in functional components is not that they are rendered via a render function, it means that they **have no state**.